# Using Selenium to navigate an HTML table created via DIV elements

Tags: html, selenium, getelementbyid

I have a table created using 'div' elements, which has dynamic content based on the choice and also the data to be displayed.

I would like to find a way to click on some icons on the last row of the table. Unable to do that using getElementID, as if there are multiple rows, then all the icons have the same ID. Is there any other way in which I can do this?

```
<div class="cv-layout">
    <div class="row cv-layout-body">
        <div class="mobile-col-12 tablet-col-12 desktop-col-12 settlement-container cv-panel">
            <div class="row header">
                <div class="tablet-col-1">Ref</div>
                <div class="tablet-col-2">Rec</div>
                <div class="tablet-col-2">Amt</div>
                <div class="tablet-col-3">Say</div>
                <div class="tablet-col-3 text-right">Pay</div>
                <div class="tablet-col-1 center-text">Age</div>
            </div>
            <div class="settlement-item">
                <div class="row settlement-read-item bordered">
                    <div class="tablet-col-1">Col1Row1</div>
                    <div class="tablet-col-2">Col2Row1</div>
                    <div class="tablet-col-2"><span>Col2aRow1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tablet-col-3">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p><span class="item-header prevent-break">Value: 356 €</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tablet-col-3 text-right">
                        <div>
                            <p><span class="item-header prevent-break"><span>XZS $34</span>
                                <!-- react-text: 1647 -->&nbsp;
                                <!-- /react-text --><span>BAS $321</span></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tablet-col-1">
                        <div class="center-text"><span class="icon-unconfirmed confirm link-icon "></span><span class="icon-edit link-icon edit"></span><span class="icon-delete link-icon remove"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You are not using `id=""` anywhere in your template. You could select using query string  like `.link-icon.confirmed`, `.link-icon.edit`, `.link-icon.remove` - or you could give those actions better naming.

Comment: You can use a CSS selector to match the class or an XPath to express a relation with another element.

Comment: Can you show us your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry did not get your comment. what work do you want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is to first locate the table which you want to perform operation on, then navigate to specific row and perform operation.

Below code will work when we know what would be the content of the row, in that case we will do getText and compare the value if value is found will click and come out of the loop, this will help in keeping things dynamics.

```
List<WebElement> tableElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'settlement-item')]")); // findElements will return a list of table elements
for (WebElement webElement : tableElement) {
 if (webElement.getText().contains(rowData)) { //rowData is the data value which we are looking for to perform operation on
          webElement.click();
          break;
}
```

2. If the idea is to get the last row and perform operation since we have the

   list we can get the length and perform certain operation on it.

   ```
   List<WebElement> tableElement = 
           driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'settlement-item')]")); // findElements will return a list of table elements
           int index = tableElement.size();
           tableElement.get(index-1).click();
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the last row with something like (I'm using Python):

```
all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.settlement-item div.row")
last_row = all_rows[-1]
```

Then click on an icon in the row:

```
unconfirmed_icon = last_row.find_element_by_css_selector("span.icon-unconfirmed")
unconfirmed_icon.click()
```